# Why do white marks on the spinners in front of engines have different patterns? Not Yellow? Omitted for some models?

Tags: aircraft-design, jet-engine, airliner, bird-strike

In [aeroailas' answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/19630/59336) I understand that the cones in front of the props/fans are called spinners.

In [Farhan's answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/12807/59336) I understand that the ehite marks painted onto the spinners act less as scarecrows and more plausibly as scare-*crew*s.

In [Daniel K's answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/83059/59336) I understand that the marks may have yellow color for high contrast.

Then I found a picture from Wikimedia showing different patterns for the white marks:
[image]

[View Original Picture](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Jet_engine_Spinners_%26_Spiral.png)

Courtesy of Gese 151, shared under CC BY-SA 4.0 license.

There are also engines lacking such patterns, as shown for this Jetblue Embracer 190

[image]

[View original picture](https://www.flickr.com/photos/kingair42/3696473641/in/photostream/)

Courtesy of John murphy, shared under CC BY-SA 2.0 licence

Here are my questions:

1. Why to the airliners have such variety of patterns? What are the pros and cons of such patterns? Why are some patterns less common?
2. Why don't they opt for other colors in practise for more contracst, like [how British use to paint their trains yellow](https://www.globalrailwayreview.com/article/26783/visibility-trains-whats-changing/)?
3. Why do some models omit them? Is the change reducing costs? Is such reduction surpassing potential risks?

Comment: I doubt anybody can offer an irrefutable answer with the level of detail you seek.  Remember there are many companies in many different country operating these planes, local custom, and pure random decisions probably have as much to do with it as anything.  Like how highway signs are different from country to country, yet they are still effective.

Comment: To be clear, my answer on that other question about yellow paint was regarding a test of an experimental prototype engine.  As far as I know all spinner patterns in production engines are white.